# Angular2 creating a new App hangs

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I have an issue that appears during the creation of a new App with the 
cmd:

```
ng new [MY_PROJECTNAME]  --prefix [MY_Prefix]
```

What I did before:

1. install npm -g install angular-cli
2. install npm -g install typings -> wich shoudn't be nescesaire!
3. after a few failing tries I also tried: npm cache clean and then retried

Versions:

- Windows 7
- node 4.4.5
- angular-cli 1.0.0 beta6

So the programm keeps hanging for quite a while (7min or so...) in the stage as shown in the Picture.

Does any one now how to fix that?

Problem in cmd while creating new App:

[image]

Comment: it looks like a network connectivity issue due to proxies, sometimes things hand until you get an error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Solution:*

As Angular University already mentioned it was due to proxies wich i used during my work. At home it worked just fine.

npm can't download package correctly if a internet connection with proxies is used.

**EDIT:**

Sometimes the problem can be solved by restarting the computer and dooing `npm chache clean`

after that works on my Computer in something like 7 minutes. (Don't ask me why)

**/EDIT**

Hope it helps other Developers

Manuel